# Eclipse CDT - Error accessing memory address 0x25a: Input/output error

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to debug a Linux C++ program under Eclipse CDT.  I've set two breakpoints in the source, when I launch the debug session however I see this in the console output:

Cannot insert breakpoint 6.
Error accessing memory address 0x25a: Input/output error.
Cannot insert breakpoint 7.
Error accessing memory address 0x8: Input/output error.

and my breakpoints are never hit.  The application does run however.  Any ideas on what the I/O errors mean?

TY,
Fred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas on what the I/O errors mean?

They mean that GDB (used by Eclipse CDT) tried to set breakpoints on address `0x25a` and `0x8`, and failed (there is no code at either of the above locations).

Why GDB decided to set breakpoints there is impossible to say: you didn't provide any details about how you have set your breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I cleared all my breakpoints then set them again (from within CDT) and they worked this time.  No explanation for the previous problems.